# How to remove one of the three switches for my foyer light fixture

Tags: switch

There are 3 light switches controlling my one foyer light fixture.  I need to remove one of them (disconnect and cover with a solid faceplate), but keep the other two working.  How do I do this?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all three switch boxes?

Comment: [This](http://users.wfu.edu/matthews/misc/switches/4WayAnimation.html) is a nice illustration of how these work. You need to wire it as if the switch you are removing  is in one position (it doesn't matter which position, the other two will work as desired).

Comment: @KeithMcClary that should be an answer...